# QtQuick QQuickItem Rendering Simple Triangle Fills the Whole Screen With Quad

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5.4

Modifying the sample found here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html. I believe I have a correct OpenGL program but it does not seem to be rendering correctly using Qt's wrapper classes. As in the sample above after everything is hooked up I have only modified the paint function. This appears as below:

```
void MainScreenRenderer::paint()
{
    if (!m_ShaderProgram) {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        m_ShaderProgram = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        m_ShaderProgram->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
            "attribute vec4 vertex;"
            "uniform mat4 mvp;"
            ""
            "void main() {"
            "    gl_Position = mvp * vertex;"
            "}");

        m_ShaderProgram->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
            "void main() {"
            "    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
            "}");

        m_ShaderProgram->bindAttributeLocation("vertex", 0);
        m_ShaderProgram->link();
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, m_ViewportSize.width(), m_ViewportSize.height());

    m_ShaderProgram->bind();

    m_ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(0);

    GLfloat values[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0, +0.0, +0.0,
        +1.0, -1.0, +0.0, +0.0,
        +0.0, +1.0, +0.0, +0.0,
    };

    QMatrix4x4 model;
    QMatrix4x4 view;
    view.lookAt(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 10.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    QMatrix4x4 projection;
    float aspect = m_ViewportSize.width() / ((m_ViewportSize.height()) ?
        m_ViewportSize.height() : 1);
    projection.perspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 1000.0);
    m_MVP = model * view * projection;

    m_ShaderProgram->setAttributeArray(0, GL_FLOAT, values, 4);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("mvp", m_MVP);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    m_ShaderProgram->disableAttributeArray(0);
    m_ShaderProgram->release();
}
```

No matter how far I pull back the camera, or re-size the window the projection seems to have no effect and it just renders red to the entire window not even accepting the fact that I just told it to render a triangle with 3 points. As seen below.

[image: Not What is Expected]

---

Following the comment the following changes have been made but now all I see is a black screen.

```
... // Vertex Shader
gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertex, 1.0);"
...

... // Data
GLfloat values[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0, +0.0,
        +1.0, -1.0, +0.0,
        +0.0, +1.0, +0.0,
    };
...

... // Vertex Attribution Setup
m_ShaderProgram->setAttributeArray(0, GL_FLOAT, values, 3); // Tuple is only 3 tightly packed.
...
```

Comment: Don't use **0.0** as your `w` coordinate. That will cause division by zero and give you a clipping headache. Use **1.0** instead, or just leave it out and use a 3D vertex position, because GL will automatically assign **1.0** for you if you do that.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman well that got rid of the big red rectangle but now I am getting a black screen. I moved the location of the camera to 1.0 assuming perhaps the object might be too small. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Given what I see of your modelview and projection matrices, this triangle is sitting on your near clipping plane if you position the camera at `z=1.0`. Try moving the eye position a few units farther down the z-axis. Ideally you'd start out in NDC space (identity modelview and projection matrix) and then once you got a triangle visible on the screen that way, start introducing camera transformations; baby steps ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I have been in and out of OpenGL for the last 5 years. I keep forgetting those baby steps. I wan't to jump back in where I left off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what I see of your modelview and projection matrices, this triangle is sitting on your near clipping plane if you position the camera at z=1.0. Try moving the eye position a few units farther down the z-axis. Ideally you'd start out in NDC space (identity modelview and projection matrix) and then once you got a triangle visible on the screen that way, start introducing camera transformations; baby steps ;) – Andon M. Coleman Mar 6 at 20:33